# The challenge of using the right endings

Tags: article

In the sentence, "...und der in einer kleinen Stadt in Deutschland lebte...", why is ein written with an 'er' ending, and why is klein written with an 'en' ending?

Comment: Hi Richard! This question is too broad. You will have to look into how cases work in German. One starting point is here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/75997/what-are-cases-used-for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Motivate cases for speakers of languages without them](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27124/motivate-cases-for-speakers-of-languages-without-them)

Comment: Please add some additional information as to what about these endings you find problematic. Potentially relevant: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/54730.

Comment: The "einer" instead of "ein" is due to the dative case here. But if you don't know the German case system that's not going to help much and I suppose the other comments are encouraging you to learn about it first. The "kleinen" instead of "klein" is due to German adjective declension, which is a whole topic in itself. The upshot is German uses a lot of word endings compared to English, and understanding them would require more explanation than would fit in one answer. I think once you get the basics of German grammar down the answers to your questions will be obvious to you.